# laravel update function does not single update

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

in laravel:
I don’t want to update all these values. In some cases, I need to update only the 'name' or 'phone number', but this update function below does not allow me to do that and updates all the values together. Please help me

update function:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $attrs = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'job'=>'required|string',
        'codemelli'=>'required|string',
        'bio'=>'required|string',
        'usermoney'=>'required|string',
        'vipuser'=>'required|string',
        'star'=>'required|string',
        'following'=>'required|string',
        'followers'=>'required|string',
    ]);

    $image = $this->saveImage($request->image, 'profiles');

    auth()->user()->update([
        'name' => $attrs['name'],
        'job'=>$attrs['job'],
        'codemelli'=>$attrs['codemelli'],
        'bio'=>$attrs['bio'],
        'usermoney'=>$attrs['usermoney'],
        'vipuser'=>$attrs['vipuser'],
        'star'=>$attrs['star'],
        'following'=>$attrs['following'],
        'followers'=>$attrs['followers'],
       
        'image' => $image
    ]);

    return response([
        'message' => 'User updated.',
        'user' => auth()->user()
    ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update specific fields without changing the entire record, you can do it like below.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $attrs = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'sometimes|required|string',
        'job'=>'sometimes|required|string',
        'codemelli'=>'sometimes|required|string',
        'bio'=>'sometimes|required|string',
        'usermoney'=>'sometimes|required|string',
        'vipuser'=>'sometimes|required|string',
        'star'=>'sometimes|required|string',
        'following'=>'sometimes|required|string',
        'followers'=>'sometimes|required|string',
    ]);
    if ($request->image) {
        $image = $this->saveImage($request->image, 'profiles');
        $attrs['image'] = $image;
     }
    auth()->user()->update($attrs);

    return response([
        'message' => 'User updated.',
        'user' => auth()->user()
    ], 200);
}
```

In the above code, I have added `sometimes` in validation which is used when you only need to validate the field if it is present in the request.